# get the duration of mp3 on Amazon S3

Tags: channel-entries, channel-files

We're using Channel Files on a build to deliver podcast episodes. The Channel Entry the episodes belong to are albums.

What we're looking to do is find a way to calculate the duration of the MP3 file automatically rather than rely on user input. We had looked at http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-getid3 but doesn't work on remote files.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Each time I've tried to reliably get the duration of an MP3 programmatically, it's been a shit-show of installing packages and caveats about VBR encoding, ID3 versions, and so on. I revert to manually entering the length every time.

Comment: yeah that tends to be what I'm finding

Comment: Where did you end up with this? I'm looking to do the same thing. :-)

Comment: nowhere I'm afraid - kind of a bummer